# Identify start and end of quotes

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string which I am parsing using for loop. I want to identify the start and end of the double/single quotes. Below, I am giving example of single quotes

```
var str = "a = 'hello \'world\''; b = 'test'";
var strInputArr = [];
var singleQuote = false;
var startIndex, endIndex;
var tmpStr = []; 
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   if(singleQuote) {
     if(str[i] === "'") {
        strInputArr.push(tmpStr.join(''));
        tmpStr = [];
        singleQuote = false;
        endIndex = i;
     }
     tmpStr.push(str[i]);
     continue;
   }
   if(str[i] === "'") {
     singleQuote = true;
     startIndex = i;
   }
}
console.log(strInputArr);
```

The output of the above code is

> ["hello ", "'", "'test"]

but it should be

> ["hello 'world'", "test"]

. How do I get the expected output?

Comment: using `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` will make your code better

Comment: @JaromandaX post it as anwser, it's the simplest possible.

Comment: No, @Salketer, because I won't be writing the code

Comment: Thank you, people, for your suggestions but this won't work in this case. I have edited the input.

Answer (score 2):

you need to change the code to

```js
var str = "a = 'hello \'world\''";
var singleQuote = false, hasLoggedStartIdx = false;
var startIndex, endIndex;
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   if(singleQuote) {
     if(str[i] === "'") {
        singleQuote = false;
        endIndex = i;
     }
     continue;
   }
   if(str[i] === "'") {
     singleQuote = true;
     if(hasLoggedStartIdx == false){
         startIndex = i;
         hasLoggedStartIdx = true;
     }
   }
}
console.log(startIndex+' - '+endIndex);
```

since you were overwriting startIndex everytime, just write to it the first time and don't write the next time

```
hasLoggedStartIdx
```

maintains if it has been written or not

since the question is updated, you can do it in the following way

```js
function getMatches(str){
    let regex1 = /'(.*)';/g;
    let regex2 = /'([^']*)'$/;
    let result = [];
    result = result.concat(regex1.exec(str)[1]);
    result = result.concat(regex2.exec(str)[1]);
    console.log(result);
}

getMatches("a = 'hello \'world\''; b = 'test'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is 1 more condition. Let me edit the question. It breaks when my str is 

var str = "a = 'hello \'world\''; b = 'new var'";

Then the expected output is 27 - 33. Assume I want to retrieve string input from the code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = "a = 'hello \'world\''";
console.log(str.indexOf('\'')+' - '+str.lastIndexOf('\''));
```

Don't try doing complicated stuff when there are very simple tools :). `indexOf` returns the first occurrence in a string (or array), while `lastIndexOf` returns the last...

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize startIndex as -1 and change code as below:

```
var startIndex = -1;

...

if(str[i] == "'") {
    singleQuote = true;
    if (startIndex == -1)
        startIndex = i;
}

...
```

Hope this might help you.